connecting windows share to chrome os
On my home network, I have a repurposed 2012 R2 Server, multiple Windows laptops and some Chromebooks. All on the same network. TP-Link wireless router. Archer A9 v6.0.
Server is plugged in directly to the router.
The Chromebooks don't have CD drives, so the kids can't use their educational software.
I have loaded the folders from the CDs onto the server.
It's all in flash, so once they can access the files, the flash emulator can play the lessons.
I can share folders from the server and from the laptops and see them from the other Windows machines.
It should be a simple matter of adding the share as seen here. But I can't see the machines or the shares from the Chromebooks. That is, my server list is empty instead of populated as shown here. I've tried typing it in by name and by IP address.
How do I troubleshoot this?
UPDATE: it looks like Chromebooks only recognize SMB protocol but the lanman service that provides it isn't running on my server.
